# InetAddress java 8 is not getting the hostname

Tags: java, java-8, inetaddress, rt.jar

`InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` is no more getting the name of the HostName since I switched to java 8 ...

with the jdk1.8 the `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` returns "localhost". Before (when I was using jdk1.6) it gives me the right hostname (which is "ACTION03") according to the network config :

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=ACTION03
```

any help ?

Comment: What does `hostname` give you?

Comment: @Robert it gives me ACTION03

Comment: You had two host entries for localhost in your host file prior to edit. Not sure if that has something to do with it. Perhaps without one to one mapping, it gives localhost? Would need to test it. Unsure of the correct behavior, but it otherwise works for me.

Comment: What is the content of the `/etc/hosts` file?

Answer (score 2):

There was [similar bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062840?focusedCommentId=13631364&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13631364) fired in JDK.

What I understand is that they changed default resolution process.

They honor configuration in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` where hosts are configured for `/etc/hosts` that gives it main priority for name resolution.

Usually `/etc/hosts` has record for `127.0.0.1 localhost` that provide name for host `localhost`

Comment: You made my day!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) with Java 1.8.0_05.

```
public class HostName {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
    }
}
```

> robert@habanero:~$ javac HostName.java && java HostName
>
> habanero

Comment: Me I have Centos 7 ! And it gives me localhost!