# How to track system load average using java

Tags: java, ubuntu

How to track system load average using java.The result should be same the load average is returning form the 'uptime' command in Linux.

Sample uptime command result is,

root@jamsheer:~# uptime

```
16:01:06 up  6:58,  2 users,  load average: 1.24, 1.25, 1.33
```

I need to get same load average through programmatically and should be executable at all platforms, Any suggestion, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can execute the uptime command from Java Runtime and parse the information from the result.

Comment: ok, Is there any solution available to execute in cross platforms?

Comment: Check my answer here, it has a sample code snippet to execute the command - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325178/in-java-8-how-do-i-get-my-hostname-without-hard-coding-it-in-my-environment/48462667#48462667

Comment: You mean you also want to execute the uptime command in windows or macos ?

Comment: Right, Should be executable in all platforms, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For platform independent result, check JMX and `OperatingSystemMXBean`:

```
OperatingSystemMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
double loadAverage = mxBean.getSystemLoadAverage();
```

Please mind that if your platform is unable to report it, the value returned will be negative, which is the result in my case on Win 7 box.